# Is the order of messages sent to the "clientOutChannel" guaranteed to be maintained when received in the "serverInChannel"?

Tags: spring-integration

I am sending messages between a TCP client - server socket pair using Spring Integration using something like this

Send client messages using

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="tcpOutboundAdapter"
                                     channel="clientOutChannel"
                                     connection-factory="factoryClient"
                                     client-mode="true"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="factoryClient"
                               type="client"
                               host="127.0.0.1"
                               port="60000"
                               single-use="false"
                               serializer="mySerDe"
                               deserializer="mySerDe"/>
```

Receive server side using

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundAdapter"
                                    channel="serverInChannel"
                                    connection-factory="factoryServer"
                                    client-mode="false/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="factoryServer"
                           type="server"
                           host="127.0.0.1"
                           port="60000"
                           single-use="false"
                           serializer="mySerDe"
                           deserializer="mySerDe"/>
```

My question is the order of messages sent to the "clientOutChannel" guaranteed to be maintained when received in the "serverInChannel"? If not, then what is the best to achieve this?

I am receiving the messages using a service activator

```
<int:service-activator id="serviceActivator"
                           ref="messageHandler"
                           method="handleMessage"
                           input-channel="serverInChannel"
                           >
    </int:service-activator>

<bean id="messageHandler" class="MessageHandler"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this, you MUST provide more context and configuration - such as your connection factory properties. Otherwise, we have to do too much speculation.

That said; on the client side, if the messages are sent on the same thread and the same socket (`single-use=false` - the default), the messages will go on the wire in the order sent.

If they are sent on different threads or sockets, there is a race condition and order is not guaranteed.

On the server side, if the messages are sent in order on the same socket by the client, they will be emitted in order, as long as `using-nio` is `false` on the server side. When `using-nio=true` on the server side, there is no guarantee of order since the messages might be dispatched on different threads.

To summarize - as long as you don't use NIO, you use a single connection, and you send the messages on the same thread, they will be received in the order sent.

Comment: Thanks Gary, this makes sense. I have added more context to the original question.